# How can I effectively run away from hostile creatures?

Tags: the-secret-world

So, I have been playing quite a bit of The Secret World over the weekend and have worked my way through the main story line in Kingsmouth.

I have noticed two things. First is that when I run into something that can squash me, usually by accident, I have a very hard time getting away. Second is that you can not kite a creature too far in a single direction with out its health being instantly restored and it returning to where it came from.

What I would like to know is how I can combine these. Clearly there is a distance I can get away from a creature in order to run away but when I am truly trying to run away I have never been able to get the creatures to break off of me.

Is there some logic that is keeping them chained on to me because they know they are going to do me in as opposed to when I am kiting them and winning they will eventually give up? Is it time based instead of distance maybe? I just can not figure this out.

Comment: In most games like this any hostile action will continue to pull the creature.  It sounds like the creatures you run away from are simply to powerful, not really a solution to this problem, the generic answer would be to become more powerful.

Comment: I've never had trouble running away unless it was stuff that could one-shot me (straying into the endgame areas accidentally).

Comment: @Shinrai Maybe that is what I am doing, I was just aiming at some hard/very hard quests when I ran into some nasties.

Comment: @James - There should be no quests that take you into the areas I'm talking about.  At least, none that I've found.

Comment: @Ramhound I must say in the Savage Coast you have those freaky looking butterflies that bumrush you. I can't get away from those, i keep running and running and they keep bumrushing and bumrushing. I didn't use a hostile action i just kept running.

Comment: Quickened Anima upgrades helps *a lot*.

Answer (score 3):

I've found one of the most effective ways to deal with hostiles following you that you're uninterested in dealing with is to kite them to the nearest encampment of friendly NPC's who can handle them for you. In Kingsmouth, the Sheriff's office is your best bet, for example, but Norma Rae, and Eddie in his dogs in the Scrapyard both also hold their own fairly well, to provide a few examples.

Particularly notable for this practice are encampments in which **The Council of Venice** have set up shop. They're well armed, have a pretty decent aggro radius, and can be found all over the place in many zones. Make a note of these encampments, because they're generally safe spots to run to.

Answer (score -1):

mostly distance related. Each mob knows its 'area', so you can in theory 'circle-kite', though in practice I find it hard to do since there are usually other mobs around.

Also, I noticed they go back if they realize they can't get to you. Like I was shooting at a mob from atop some garbage container, and got it to like about half health and it couldn't reach me, but then suddenly it just gave up and went back to his area with full health.

Comment: Not always the case, some of them will actually follow you across the map. In some instances I've found that 'hiding out of reach' doesn't work either, and they will be able to mysteriously cause damage to you even though it would be physically impossible to do so (ie: standing on the roof of the Sycoil station in Savage Coast, zombies can still get you up there)